# How to fix the "Base table or view not found: 1146" error when running 'php artisan migrate' command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to rum `php artisan migrate` to generate table migration, but I am getting an error:

> [2016-03-08 05:49:01] local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with
> message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'testing.permissions' doesn't exist' in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\LMS-testing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:333

I have tried [Base table or view not found: 1146 Table Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159257/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-5) and [Doing a Laravel tutorial, getting "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sdbd_todo.migrations' doesn't exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511709/doing-a-laravel-tutorial-getting-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-sdb) but did not succeed.

I have also tried to run `php artisan list` but getting the same error.

**Updated**

```
**RolesPermission migration table**

Schema::create('roles', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('label');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();            
        });
        
        Schema::create('permissions', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('label');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();            
        });
        
        Schema::create('permission_role', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            
            $table->foreign('permission_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('permissions')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->foreign('role_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('roles')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
        });
        
        Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            
            $table->foreign('role_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('roles')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
            
        });


.env file
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=W8YWZe3LCngvZzexH3WLWqCDlYRSufuy

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=log
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Can you please share the migration file code?

Comment: updated, kindly check.

Comment: even i am not able to run php artisan make or any other command. I am getting same error for creating controller or model.

Comment: Can you post your .env file, especially which related to database connection?

Comment: Updated with .env file please check.

Comment: The possible reason is you already have `permissions` and/or `roles` tables in your target database `(testing as per your .env)`.
Try deleting these tables before you run the `migration` command.
If that is not the case then some of your other migration that apparently run before this migration is creating those table. Please write here if that is the case or not

Comment: No, Database is blank. I have drop all the tables from DB, after that i am trying to migrate.

Comment: And what about the other migrations in your `database/migrations` directory? Are we sure that other migrations aren't doing anything with these tables.

Comment: Yes, i have checked. other migration not using it. I have created seeders.

Comment: I have resolved my issue. Thanks every one for the support.

Comment: You resolved your issue. Can you please share how you solved it? Struggling with the same exact problem.

Comment: Kindly check the name and order of your migration, migration will execute in the order.

Comment: Same problem, it seems Laravel executes AppServiceProvider code, even for migrations. I commented everything in the boot function, migrate, and uncomment. Worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

Check your migration file, maybe you are using Schema::table, like this:

```
Schema::table('table_name', function ($table)  {
    // ...
});
```

If you want to create a new table you must use Schema::create:

```
Schema::create('table_name', function ($table)  {
    // ...
});
```

Laracast [More information in this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-migrate-base-table-or-view-not-found).

Answer (score 20):

I just had the same problem.

My solution was to comment what I had put into the `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider` (because in there I had Model request that didn't exist more).

Comment: Yapp this work! I put something on boot method of AppServiceProvider and I should comment it before migrate:fresh --seed

Comment: first run AppServiceProvider  then run migration !!! it`s strange . [i use laravel 6 ]

Comment: Solution for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41997872/6926281

Answer (score 12):

I ran it to a similar problem.

Seems like I executed a Model query in the routes file. So it executes every time, even before running the actual migration.

```
//Problematic code
Route::view('users', 'users', [ 'users' => User::all() ]);
```

So I changed it to

```
Route::get('/users', function () {
    return view('users', ['users' => User::all()]);
});
```

And everything works fine. Make sure that no Model queries is excecuted on the execution path and then try migrating.

Comment: I had `Auth::loginUsingId` in web.php which caused the error. Thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 6):

Check all of your service providers. In one of the boot methods, a model may be called, the migration to which has not yet been run.

Comment: ty for this, been searching everywhere!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I tried to migrate new database. I had a function in AuthServiceProvider which selects all permissions.
I commented that function and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Had the same here with a shared provider which used the database.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the foreign keys are added but cannot find the table because it hasn't been created.

1) make tables without foreign keys

2) Make a 9999_99_99_999999_create_foreign_keys.php file

3) put there the foreign keys you want. With the 999..9 .php file it makes sure that it does the foreign keys last after the tables have been made.

4) You have added the tables first and then added the foreign keys. This will work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'testing.permissions' doesn't exist
```

So the table `permissions` doesn't exist. Now let's look at the migrations:

```
Schema::create('permission_role', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('permission_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('permissions')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
    });
```

We can see in this `Schema` call that you are defining a foreign key to the `permissions` table.

With this, we can assume that Laravel is trying to create this foreign key, but the table that it wants to refer to doesn't exist.

This usually happens when the order of the migration files is not equal the order in wich the tables must be created. So, if I have the migrations files in this order in my `migrations` folder:

```
2016_10_09_134416_create_permission_role_table 
2016_10_09_134416_create_permissions_table
```

They will be executed in that order. But if I know that `permission_role` dependes on `permissions`, I need to change their positions by changing the timestamp in their file names:

```
2016_10_09_134415_create_permissions_table 
2016_10_09_134416_create_permission_role_table
```

In this case I've changed only the last digit from `create_permissions_table` so it will be less than the timestamp from `create_permissions_role_table`. After this, don't forget to run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

So composer can be aware of your change.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, see more here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49300262/5129122

```
    try {

        return Permission::with('role')->get();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        return [];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who end up being here because of the "migrations" table is not created automatically. In some cases you need to run the following artisan command:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

OR with code:

```
Artisan::call('migrate:install', [
    '--database' => 'your_database_connection', // optional
]);
```

to get your base "migrations" table, not sure why it is not generated automatically but it does happened.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem once, I guess the problem is not in your migrations, but looks like permissions are checked before you create permission tables in DB. make sure you does not have `auth` `middleware` added in your route. or comment out any service provider that uses permissions tables from `config/app.php`. Most probably removing `auth` `middleware` from the route till you generate migration will solve your problem

Comment: I am not using default providers except collactive Html. I have also removed all code from route. still getting same error.

Comment: Well in my case this worked. I don't get though why it has any impact on the migrations... Does migrate boot laravel and check code?

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else runs in to this I just had the same issue and the reason it was happening was because I had created several commands and then needed to rollback my db to rerun the migrations.

To fix it I had to comment out the contents of the

```
protected $commands = []
```

in app\Console\Kernel.php file.

Phew!!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was to disable PermissionsServiceProvider in config/app.php before migrating.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your boot method on AppServiceProvider. if you're using any model request on there, please comment them and migrate again. Your problem will be resolved