# Laravel 5.3 make a query to database and pass it all views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a some dynamic data that I want to fetch from database and pass it to all views. I tried to make some examples from internet but they seems to be not working in my situation like

```
public function boot(){}
```

to which I can't make a database query only pass hardcoded values. 
Another method I have tried is a base controller but the view gives me error when accessing the variable

```
$query = DB::table('users')->first();
\View::share('user', $query);
```

Anyone have a BaseController based solution will be appreciated and if I missed something please do remind me

Comment: Isn't it better to register the query in a singleton in the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container) and resolve it when you need it?

Comment: can you explain more or give any reference . thank u

Comment: You could also make a blade template and include it in there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views:

> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method.

Again as an example in that site you should add this to one of your service providers:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        if (!app()->runningInConsole()) {
            $query = DB::table('users')->first();
            \View::share('user', $query);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am making a query to database and i have read in some articals that boot method is called before the Eloquent

Comment: @FaisalMehmoodAwan so you're saying this solution is not working? Also this is the query builder. Eloquent is not the same thing.

Comment: The boot method is called when you are migrating. In a new environment the database tables have not been migrated. This code should be commented out in a new environment for the first migration, then enable it again.

Comment: @Halfacht I've updated with an alternative way to not run the code when running in the console

Comment: I've added `|| app()->runningUnitTests()`. Because the HTTP tests fail without

Answer (score 0):

You can use view composer.
"View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location."

you can find more detail on https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers

Comment: can you please provide a refference that use a database logic . because i am looking at it and it passes the hardcoded values to view

Comment: Just include your model function in ViewComposers __constructor. There are one more example please check this also

https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers

Answer (score 0):

It is working from boot :

```
View::share ('variabelname', DB table first () etc etc)
```

However i encounter a problem :

If i delete tables or drop tables, then run migration and seed, I got **error** :

> base tabel / view not found.

So i have to comment out that line from App Service Provider before any migrate refresh etc.