# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prj_roocket.permissions' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel

I create a migration

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['role_id' , 'permission_id']);
    });

    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['role_id' , 'user_id']);
    });
```

Any what I write in CMD `php artisan migrate and composer dumpautoload and php artisan serve and...` This error is seen. and too I deleted database and I create a new database.

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'prj_roocket.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'prj_roocket.permissions' doesn't exist

Comment: have you migrated after creating the new database?

Comment: Can you check manually if the table exists in you database prj_roocket? If not check, try to run ```php artisan migrate:refresh``` and check if their are some errors.

Comment: Try clearing the cache maybe - php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is given by the function **getPermissions** in **AuthServiceProvider** (or somewhere else you defined your authentication service provider).

Probabily your function looks like this:

```
protected function getPermissions()
{
    return Permission::with('roles')->get();
}
```

Try to replace the function **getPermissions** with:

```
protected function getPermissions()
{
    try {
        return Permission::with('roles')->get();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

and then run **php artisan migrate** again.

Note: with this fix you are not going to compromise the system security.